# Is breathing into a paper bag an effective treatment for panic attacks?

Tags: effectiveness, anxiety-disorders, panic-attack, hyperventilation, carbon-dioxide

[Some sources](http://www.webmd.com/anxiety-panic/using-a-paper-bag-to-control-hyperventilation) claim that breathing into a paper bag is a good way to control hyperventilation caused by a panic attack. The theory (I surmise) is that re-breathing CO<sub>2</sub> helps to mitigate the respiratory alkalosis caused by hyperventilation. If the alkalosis is perpetuating the anxiety, this seems like a logical intervention. Has this been shown to be an effective intervention for panic attacks?

Answer (score 2):

I did not find any studies which would investigate that matter. Moreover, in 2008 Nillni and co-workers [(1)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3254702/) stated:

> Surprisingly, although the expressed goal of breathing training is to correct hyperventilation, pCO2 has never been used as an outcome measure

In a recent study [(2)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22901344) it was concluded:

> Clinical improvement must have depended on elements common to both
>   breathing therapies rather than on the effect of the therapies
>   themselves on CO(2) levels.

As so I would conclude that even in theoretical level there is very limited evidence for that intervention to be effective.

But I would your use very different perspective. I bet that if you choose ten people out of the street and ask them "What would you do if your friend had a panic attack?" more than half would respond that they would give him/her a paper bag. The use of paper bag as an emergency intervention is a very common factoid. With this matter there exists a major *placebo* effect with that treatment. Use of paper bag as an emergency measure for person with a panic attack is very cost-effective without any potential side effects so it is an ideal "intervention". So I think we should not crave for solid evidence. Due to the factoid matter majority of people *think* it is an effective treatment and with comes a great placebo effect which should be definitely used due to the cost-effectiveness and safety.

Answer (score 2):

Breathing into a paper bag to control hyperventilation might improve hypocarbia, but should NOT be done because of the risks of hypoxia and death.

This [case report](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2499228/) shows that breathing into a paper bag during hyperventilation can reduce partial pressure of oxygen by up to 42 mmHg (normal 80-100mmHg) and can result in death.

As answered by @arkiaamu, a better treatment would be [reassurance, pursed lip breathing, and breathing exercises](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/hyperventilation) to restore regular breathing pattern.

**Case Report Source**:
Callaham M. Hypoxic hazards of traditional paper bag rebreathing in hyperventilating patients. Ann Emerg Med. 1989;18(6):622-628. doi:10.1016/s0196-0644(89)80515-3